# How can I sort a JavaScript array by specific criteria?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I have an array like:

```
[0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,0...]
```

I have to pass for each element a letter in this form:

```
[A, B, C1, C2, D, E, F1, F2, F3, G...]
```

When the value is zero, or undefined or null need a new letter, otherwise need a new one again but as times as the same number stays there. There are two of 1 then I need C1, C2, later is there three of 2 so I need F three times.

Can you give me some hints to solve this issue?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, what happens if you have `[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]`? Do you start a new letter sequence for the `2`s or continue the old one?

Comment: 2 needs a new letter yeah. :)

Comment: What is the expected output? A flat array like this: `[C1, C2, F1, F1, F2, F2, ...]`?

Comment: What if out of the range  like after  ```Z``` ?

Comment: @adiga the first array was generated from a method, then I need to generate the new one by the logic of the first one.

Comment: @ikhvjs I need to use just the alphabet for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a closure over letter and count and return eiter the same letter as before with count or just the letter.

```js
const
    values = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0],
    result = values.map(((letter, count) => (v, i, { [i - 1]: prev }) => {
        if (v) {
            if (prev && v !== prev) {
                ++letter;
                count = 1;
            }
            return letter.toString(36).toUpperCase() + count++;
        }
        if (count !== 1) ++letter;
        count = 1;
        return (letter++).toString(36).toUpperCase();
    })(10, 1));

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: I have stuck with your script a bit in that case when I have an array like for example [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0]. I get results [A, B, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, D] so at 1 and 2 and 2 and 3 don't change the letter.

Comment: @DánielBoros, it needs another check. please see edit.

Comment: it seems good, but the number should start from 1 when the letters are changed. Sorry I was not exact.

Comment: I think I should take count = 1 in the second if statement and everything will be perfect.

Comment: I need for result an array like this: [A B C1 C2 D1 D2 E1 E2 E3 F]